# Camel: how to set boolean header parameter using simple comparison?

Tags: type-conversion, apache-camel

I am trying to set a header parameter (`param2`), using [simple expression language](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html):

```
from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
    .setBody(constant("on,off"))
    .split()
    .tokenize(",")
    .setHeader("param1", simple("${body}"))
    .setHeader("param2", simple("${header.param1} == 'on'"))
    .log("param1 = [${header.param1}], param2 = [${header.param2}]");
```

But as result I get a string set instead of a boolean value, the following gets logged:

```
param1 = [on], param2 = [on == 'on']
param1 = [off], param2 = [off == 'on']
```

I would expect it log:

```
param1 = [on], param2 = [true]
param1 = [off], param2 = [false]
```

Documentation writes, that it is possible to do comparison using `simple` and I can get it working when doing choices:

```
from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
    .setBody(constant("on,off"))
    .split()
    .tokenize(",")
    .setHeader("param1", simple("${body}"))
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${header.param1} == 'on'"))
            .setHeader("param2", constant(true))
        .otherwise()
            .setHeader("param2", constant(false))
        .end()
    .log("param1 = [${header.param1}], param2 = [${header.param2}]");
```

The output then is:

```
param1 = [on], param2 = [true]
param1 = [off], param2 = [false]
```

But why it is not working then in direct assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I tested with 2.12.3, 2.13.0, 2.12-SNAPSHOT and 2.13-SNAPSHOT and the operators are not handled correctly. Even setting the output type did not help.

By the way, you may also use Groovy to solve your problem:

```
 .setHeader("param2").groovy("request.headers.param1.equals('on')")
```

**EDIT:**
This bug was fixed in 2.12.4, 2.13.1 and 2.14.0, see [CAMEL-7298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7298)

Comment: Good to know, that the way I've tried to set the header was correct. Thanks for taking time to solve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can define the result type of à simple expression, like so

```
.setHeader("param2", simple("${header.param1} == 'on'", Boolean.class))
```

Comment: Hi, I tested your suggestion: value gets casted to boolean, but logically not correct - in both cases `param2` value is always `false`

Comment: Have you tried to to change the order of operands just in case it is some non-obvious casting issue: `simple("'on' == ${header.param1}", Boolean.class)`.

Comment: You wrote in the first post that the value gets logged as param1 = [on], param2 = [on == 'on']. Well [on == 'on'] would return false, since the value is not the same. What happens if you try to remove the single quotes? As in  simple("${header.param1} == on", Boolean.class)

Comment: Yes do as Daniel, and specify boolean as the output type. And we fixed in recent Camel releases so it works by eval as predicate, and not casting to boolean as before. So upgrade your Camel or use another language, than simple.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Specifying the output type, does not fix the problem. I tested with 2.12.3, 2.13.0, 2.12-SNAPSHOT and 2.13-SNAPSHOT and unfortunately the operators are not handled correctly using all these versions.

Comment: You need to build from source to make sure SNAPSHOT is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using an expression language like [MVEL](https://camel.apache.org/mvel.html). Use the camel mvel component and write your route as

```
        from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
            .setBody(constant("on,off"))
            .split()
            .tokenize(",")
            .setHeader("param1", simple("${body}"))
            .setHeader("param2").mvel("request.headers.param1 == 'on'")
            .log("param1 = [${header.param1}], param2 = [${header.param2}]");
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with `Mvel` as well as with `SpEL` too, though I am still interested why it is not the case with `simple`

Comment: @Laimoncijus This is a bug, see my answer.